# How do I fix this security hole?

Tags: php, html

I have a website that currently works. It has a page that displays information, and another that lets you edit the information sources. Now when you login on index.php it posts the data to view.php through a form. The site doesn't use any cookies. When I click edit, it posts the username, passhash, and the submit request to edit.php. Currently, this button works well, but the current code for the edit button is as follows:

```
<FORM NAME ="form1" METHOD ="post" ACTION = "edit.php">
<p class="BodyText">
<INPUT TYPE = "Hidden" Name = "Username" Value = "<?php print($username); ?>">
<INPUT TYPE = "Hidden" Name = "PassHash" Value = "<?php print($password); ?>">
<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Change" VALUE = "Edit">
</p>
</FORM>
```

I hadn't noticed before, but now I notice as I look through the code, that it prints the password. I don't really know how else to get the password to the edit page without this, but when I inspect the element in Chrome, I can see the password hash (SHA-1). Firstly, and I assume yes, is this a security hole? Secondly, how to I pass the passhash along to the edit.php page without sending the hash back to the end user. Thirdly, am I doing this wrong entirely? It seems OK to me to login through post, but is that security crazy? I'm kinda new at PHP, and new at security entirely.

Comment: The password is transferred on the first login page anyway. What you're trying to do here is minimizing the transfers to one page. And it's just that. Security-wise the index.php script is the major obstacle. Enable SSL for all pages instead of obsessing about a second or third POST request.

Comment: CP**Cookie**Man should use cookies (or sessions)

Answer (score 4):

This is not a good way to do this (hidden inputs in the form).

Learn about [PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

Check out some of the examples from the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).

You'll want to preserve the user's access across their session between pages and you should never print out their passwords.

You can validate users' passwords to authenticate them, and have the session hold information on who the user is, and whether they are logged in for that session (rather than trying to validate passwords on every single page).

One example flow:

When authenticating (user logs in):

```
session_start();

// Authenticate user here with the password.
if (someAuthenticationFunction($_POST['user'], $_POST('password') === true) {
    $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true; // Notice we're not saving the password into the session, only whether user is loggedIn.
}
```

On every other page where you would want to check user's authentication (most likely on edit.php page):

```
session_start();

if ($_SESSION['loggedIn'] === true) {
    $user = $_SESSION['user'];
    // Do the actual editing stuff here.
}
```

Once the user is ready to log out, use `session_destroy()` (most likely on a logout page).

Comment: Your link didn't provide much help. Is this here a better resource? http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: @CPCookieMan How you implement the session depends on how you're authenticating the user (using the password, etc). In your session, some things you might want to preserve are: Username possibly, whether the user is authenticated for this session. The edit page should check for whether the session is authenticated, NOT against the password hash. When users log out, simply destroy the session.

Answer (score 3):

u can save the password in the $_SESSION variable.
For it you have to write in the page where the login form gets processed:

```
session_start();//at top of the page
$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];
```

After this is set you can get the username in every file where

```
session_start();
```

is written.

Comment: This seems like a very good answer right here. Every file has to have session_start(); to access these variables?

Comment: @CPCookieMan No, only the authentication page should have session_start(); Every other page checks whether session is set.

Comment: @StefanGi Oops, my mistake. You can use session_start() to resume existing sessions. (Documentation.)[http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php]

Comment: So... yes? I do it on every page?

Comment: on every page where u Safe the username or where u want to read it out

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use cookies, you could use some kind of session ID passed in the URL (see [php.net/output_add_rewrite_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.output-add-rewrite-var.php)) and store it in a database, but then you'd be opening a whole new can of worms to do with session hijacking. COokie-based PHP sessions are the way to go.